# How to implement scala generic function that takes subtype of parameterized traits and returns it

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

I don't need any information about type T on runtime so I think ClassTag is useless here.

I just need to return in my function the same type I've taken as an argument.

```scala
class MyClass[T] extends A with B[T] with C with D

trait A
trait B[T] {
  def usefulMethod: Unit = println("B")
}
trait C
trait D {
 def usefulMethodToo: Unit = println("D")
}
```

I've tried to implement my function like this but compiler infers `Nothing`

```scala
def helper[T, A <: B[T] with D](x: A): A = {
  x.usefulMethod
  x.usefulMethodToo
  x
}

helper(new MyClass[Int])
```

Can it be inferred by compiler somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that it can't infer `T`, but in this (maybe oversimplified?) case you don't actually need it:

```
def helper[A <: B[_] with D](x: A): A = {
  x.usefulMethod
  x.usefulMethodToo
  x
}
```

This workaround works too:

```
def helper[T, A <: B[T] with D](x: A with B[T]): A = {
  x.usefulMethod
  x.usefulMethodToo
  x
}
```

Comment: I think `def helper[A <: B[_] with D](x: A): A` is the best one because A in that case can have any amount of type parameters

Comment: It depends on the specific requirements. But here the `B[_] with D` option is simpler and if it's sufficient for your purposes, sure, use it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I guess that in your particular case `MyClass` has also a type, maybe that is the reason why compiler can not infer it.
I would try next:

```
def helper[T, A[_] <: B[_] with D](x: A[T]): A[T] = {
    x.usefulMethod
    x.usefulMethodToo
    x
  }
```

Unfortunately this won't work for case like `class IntMyClass extends B[Int] with D` - but I don't have better ideas for now.
Hope this helps!